# Nightwatch clear browser

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I have different tests that I would like to launch in clean browser, like on incognito mode with clear localstorages, cookies, sessions and so on. However, it seems that each test runs on the same browser instance. I tried using browser.end() but it doesn't work. The tests should run on phantom driver, so the newest selenium methods for clearing local Storages don't work.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the before and after hooks in nightwatch.
My after.js looks like below

```
module.exports = function (client) {
  client.end();
};
```

you can call it in your testFile.js as,

`after:after`

afterEach and beforEach might be helpful as well.  Here is the reference on nightwatchjs.org http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-before-each-and-after-each-hooks

Not sure if this answers your question, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: ```afterEach: function(client) {
      client.end();
    }
``` solved it for me.